# How to solve python: OSError: [Errno 123] other os error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

when I'm trying to add the time to the name of a file using the `datetime.datetime.now()`, i get: 'OSError: [Errno 123] other os error'

I tried using `time.time()`, but i feel like that's unnecessary as `datetime.datetime.now()` can give the time...

```
shot.save(path+'//'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.png')
```

the error:

```
    Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 240, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "C:\Users\SQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\SQ\Desktop\Screenshot\02.pyw", line 8, in on_press
    check_key(key)
  File "C:\Users\SQ\Desktop\Screenshot\02.pyw", line 25, in check_key
    shot.save(path+'//'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.png')
OSError: [Errno 123] other os error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SQ\Desktop\Screenshot\02.pyw", line 40, in <module>
    listener.join()
  File "C:\Users\SQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 210, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "C:\Users\SQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\SQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 240, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "C:\Users\SQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\SQ\Desktop\Screenshot\02.pyw", line 8, in on_press
    check_key(key)
  File "C:\Users\SQ\Desktop\Screenshot\02.pyw", line 25, in check_key
    shot.save(path+'//'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.png')
OSError: [Errno 123] other os error
[Finished in 5.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\SQ\Desktop\Screenshot\02.pyw"]
```

Comment: Can you include the full error message?

Comment: have you look at the string you get from str(datetime.datetime.now())? it is probably something that can not be a valid path.

Comment: The default string representation of a `datetime.datetime` instance uses colon to delimit the time fields. Microsoft's file systems such as NTFS and FAT32 reserve this character in filenames. (Some non-Microsoft file systems in Windows, as well as Microsoft's named-piped file system, do allow colon in filenames, but it's not worth considering in general.) Using colon in a filename is always an error in FAT32. In NTFS, it might correspond to a valid stream name of the form "filename:streamname:streamtype", e.g. "spam.txt:eggs:$DATA".

Comment: Why do you have two forward slashes in the path?

Comment: that solved it... thanks @Lior Cohen